# Styling a jQuery Plug-In (ClassyCountdown)

Tags: javascript, jquery, countdown

I am using the Countdown from this site: http://www.class.pm/files/jquery/classycountdown/

Now I want to style the Countdown, but I don´t know how. I want to edit the font, the color, the thickness of the line and scale the whole Countdown. How do I style it?

EDIT: working Link: http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/a/51105/demo.html

EDIT 2: I figured out how to scale the whole Countdown. I simply used the width of the id and it resized automatically.

```
#countdown-container {
    width: 500px;
}
```

But how to change font, color and the thickness of the line?

Comment: The link is broken for me...

Comment: http://www.html.it/wp-content/uploads/script/demo/a/51105/demo.html

thank you, this link should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to scale the whole Countdown. I simply used the width of the id and it resized automatically.

```
#countdown-container {
    width: 500px;
}
```